# Pipe stdout to another process's file descriptor

Tags: bash

This one is foiling me so far. I know how to redirect my stdout to another file descriptor in the same process. I know how to pipe stdout to another process's stdin. But what if I want to pipe a process's stdout to a file descriptor in another process?? Specifically, for the case of while read...

```
  cat file | while read -u 9 line; do //some stuff; done
```

How do I get cat's output onto file descriptor 9 of the while loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipes work *specifically* with standard input and output (file descriptors 0 and 1); they don't generalize to other descriptors. Use process substitution and input redirection instead.

```
while read -u 9 line; do
  ...
done 9< <(cat file)
```

Of course, you shouldn't use `cat` like this; just use regular input redirection

```
while read -u 9 line; do
  ...
done 9< file
```

---

Bonus, POSIX-compliant answer: use a named pipe.

```
mkfifo p
cat file > p &
while read line <&9; do
  ...
done 9< p
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip the [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and directly open fd 9:

```
while read -u 9 line; do //some stuff; done 9< file
```

If you do want to use `cat` or some other arbitrary command, you wouldn't use a pipe at all. A pipe hooks stdout to stdin, but fd 9 is neither of those. Instead you'd want to open up the file descriptor first and then directly run the command that reads from it.

```
exec 9< <(cat file)
while read -u 9 line; do //some stuff; done
```

You could also combine it with the first answer if you want to do it all in one line.

```
while read -u 9 line; do //some stuff; done 9< <(cat file)
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the thought. You're correct that works, but perhaps I should have chosen something other than cat to demonstrate. The actual input I have is NOT from a file, it's from stdout of a process (other than cat, it's grep in reality) This is simply an example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are reading from file descriptor 9 in a pipeline like this, but can you try something like this:

```
cat test.in 9>&1 | while read -u 9 line; do
    echo ${line}
done 9<&0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Presumably, one would use a different file descriptor because something else in the body of the loop is reading from file descriptor 0, and you don't want it reading from `test.in` as well.