# Shell variable value passing to subshell?

Tags: shell

I am writing script in shell and it's something like:

```
temp=0
while true; do
    case "a" in
        a) temp=5; ;;
    esac
    break
done | echo "$temp"
```

( temp value is condition for if in subshell and | (pipe) is needed as stdout redirect to stdin)
and I need in temp 5 but I got 0 in echo. Any way to preserve value inside case (posixly correct without tempfile)?

Comment: In `while true; do case "a" in a) temp=5; ;; esac; break; done | echo "$temp"`, the `$temp` on the right hand side of the pipe is evaluated before the while loop is executed.

Comment: Please show what you're actually trying to do in the right side of the pipe. Piping to `echo` doesn't make sense since `echo` doesn't read from stdin. We need to know what you're really doing because the answers will vary based on what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this? Prints 5 and 0.

```
#!/bin/sh
temp=0
while true; do
    case "a" in
        a) temp=5; echo "$temp" ;;
    esac
    break
done | cat

echo "temp unchanged because of subshell $temp"
```

Would this help you, filtering out your status?
I still don't get why you need a pipe and how you expect the other command you pipe into to react on a status. It's just not the way it works. You evaluate conditions in your script and call commands accordingly.

```
#!/bin/sh
filter(){
    data=''
    while read line; do
        case "$line" in
            temp=5) temp=5 ;;
            *) data=$(printf '%s\n' "$data"; printf '%s\n' "$line") ;;
        esac
    done

    if [ "$temp" -eq 5 ]; then
        echo "do this 5 with data"
    else
        echo "do that other with data"
        echo "$data"
    fi
}

temp=0
while true; do
    case "a" in
        a) temp=5; printf 'temp=%s\n' "$temp"; for i in $(seq 1 30); do echo "30 lines"; done ;;
    esac
    break
done | filter

echo "temp unchanged because of subshell $temp"
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need to stdout and stdin unchanged. Point is to pass variable and stdout to subshell

Comment: stdout and stdin unchanged? So no pipe? Because in your question you say you want to pipe?

Comment: I need to pipe stdout (30 lines) to stdin (30 lines) and pass that variable, which decide, what should happen with those lines

Comment: Maybe use [another file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557207/pipe-stdout-to-another-processs-file-descriptor).

Comment: sadly I don't have those 20 lines in file and I am not allowed to create temporarily file

Comment: It's all about files in shell. So the answer is no. Subshells do not modify parent shell variables.

Comment: Why do you need a pipe?